# how to validate a username value with mysql and java to avoid duplicate user name

Tags: java, mysql

good day, i have a problem with this method, for some reason it gives me an error. "Java.sql.SqlException: statement is not executing". But it checks if the value is duplicate and prompts the error as the method below show. This has stopped my registration from completing. thanks for your help

```
public static void UserExists(String y){

                try{

                 query = " select * from MailRegister where Username=?";
                 pst = connect.prepareStatement(query); //passes my query to java predefined prepared statement
                 pst.setString(1, Username.getText()); //passes the value of the username to the prepared statement
                 rs = pst.executeQuery(); //this would execute the query passed in the prepared statement
                 if(rs.next()){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Sorry This Username is Taken");
                 }
                  pst.close();
                 rs.close();


                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);//shows error dialog
                }

            }
```

Comment: And the full stack trace you get is...?  Where does `connect` come from?  Try posting a self contained runnable sample of your code that has the problem and the full error you are getting.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, let me paste a full runable code for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get this error because your objects are not closed properly all the time. Your `connect` is breaking. A good practice is to open and close the connection when required to prevent leaks.

In the code above, `pst.close();` and `rs.close();` should be in a `finally`.

Or even cleaner, the prepared statement should go inside a :

```
try (pst = connect.prepareStatement(query)) {...}
```

That way you don't have to close it yourself, the JVM will handle it for you.

Comment: thanks for the information, am grateful, i would try it and get back to you @Guillaume

Comment: As a side note, you also should enforce this rule in the database with a `unique index` pointing to your username column.